# how to run multiple lines of code at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe

may I know how do I execute the code block at once instead of running it line by line? I tried using pipe but does not seem to work well...Anyway, many thanks for helping.

```
library(quantmod)

calc_pnl<-function(close,dividends,buy_price,buy_date){
  names(close) <- "close"
  names(dividends) <- "div"
  # merge close and cumsum divs from buy_date
  out <- merge(close[paste0(buy_date, "/")], cumsum(dividends[paste0(buy_date, "/")]))
  
  # roll divs forward on the empty values
  out$div <- na.locf(out$div)
  
  # calculate buy_price as close - buy_price + divs
  out$pnl <- out$close - buy_price + out$div
  
  out
}

  
start<-'2010-01-01'
end<- '2022-10-21'

symbols<-'T'
ticker <- na.omit(getSymbols(symbols,from = start, to = end,auto.assign=FALSE)) 
ticker_dividend<-round(getDividends(symbols,from=start,to=end),2)
buy_1<-max(ticker[,4])
buy_2<-min(ticker[,4])
buy_3<-mean(ticker[,4])

pnl_max<-calc_pnl_max(ticker[,4],ticker_dividend,buy_price = buy_1 ,buy_date = start)
pnl_min<-calc_pnl_max(ticker[,4],ticker_dividend,buy_price = buy_2 ,buy_date = start) 
pnl_avg<-calc_pnl_max(ticker[,4],ticker_dividend,buy_price = buy_3 ,buy_date = start) 

df<-round(tail(cbind(pnl_max$pnl,pnl_min$pnl,pnl_avg$pnl),8),2)
colnames(df)<-c('maxPnL','minPnL','avgPnL') 
df$var<-(df$maxPnL/df$minPnL)
df
```

Comment: just put everything in a script and run the script/source the script etc

Comment: select all (ctr+a) and press ctrl+enter?